# Visual Studio can't find System.Globalization.PersianCalendar

Tags: windows-phone-8, calendar, persian

I need to use an object of type `System.Globalization.PersianCalendar` in my Windows Phone app but Visual Studio can't find it!

Is there anything I can do? I have latest VS13 running in windows 8 x64.

Comment: How did you create the Windows Phone app?

Answer (score 1):

It is not available for Windows Phone according to this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

From Link:

> **Version Information**
>
> .NET Framework
> Supported in: 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0
>
> .NET Framework Client Profile
> Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1
>
> **Platforms**
>
> Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 7, Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core Role not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core Role supported with SP1 or later; Itanium not supported)

See if the [`HijriCalendar Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.globalization.hijricalendar(v=vs.105).aspx)  will work for you.

Comment: thanks but the same thing is written for [HijriCalenndar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.hijricalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [GregorianCalendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but they are available there! and anyway that is a simple class. can't I add it to my assembly?

Comment: @hasan just updated link it was broken, the calendar  is available for windows phone. You should be able to access it, it is under the `System.Globalization` Namespace

Comment: @hasan The reason you can't use it is? It appears to be the only option for windows phone.